# get table rows only when table checkbox is "checked"

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am using below code to retrieve the values of selected row using `checkbox class = btnSelect`.

I want to get the rows only when the `checkbox` is marked as checked.

Current code get the values, both when `checkbox` is checked and unchecked.

Why does the code below get the values when the checkbox is either checked or unchecked?

```
$("#itemtable").on('click', '.btnSelect', function() {
   // get the current row 
   alert("i am inside dddd");
   var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");

   var col1 = currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text(); // get SI no from checkbox
   var col2 = currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text(); // get item name
   var col3 = currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").text(); // get item code
   var col4 = currentRow.find("td:eq(3)").text(); // get supplier
   var col5 = currentRow.find("td:eq(4)").text(); // get received qty
   var col6 = $(currentRow).find("td:eq(5) input[type='text']").val(); // get accepted qty
   var col7 = $(currentRow).find("td:eq(6) input[type='text']").val(); // get rejected qty
   var col8 = $(currentRow).find("td:eq(7) input[type='text']").val(); // get remarks

   var data = col1 + "\n" + col2 + "\n" + col3 + "\n" + col4 + "\n" + col5 + "\n" + col6 + "\n" + col7 + "\n" + col8;

   alert(data);
});
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: add conditional state if checkbox is checked

Comment: yes i am struck in that, could u please help me to give correct snippet instead of .btnSelect verification

Comment: sure add the render html mark up so i can create a demo

Comment: Please check https://jsfiddle.net/selv/nxcuw9xx/

Comment: @guradio when i click save button i want to get the row values of selected checkbox

Comment: check the answer i provide it have the event click on the save button not on the checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#saverecord").click(function(event) {
    //$("#itemtable").on('click', '.btnSelect', function() {
    // get the current row 

    var currentRow = $(".btnSelect:checked").closest("tr");
    console.log(currentRow.index())
    var col1 = currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text(); // get SI no from checkbox
    var col2 = currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text(); // get item name
    var col3 = currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").text(); // get item code
    var col4 = currentRow.find("td:eq(3)").text(); // get supplier
    var col5 = currentRow.find("td:eq(4)").text(); // get received qty
    var col6 = currentRow.find("td:eq(5)").text()
    var col7 = currentRow.find("td:eq(6)").text()
    var col8 = currentRow.find("td:eq(7)").text()

    var data = col1 + "\n" + col2 + "\n" + col3 + "\n" + col4 + "\n" + col5 + "\n" + col6 + "\n" + col7 + "\n" + col8;

    console.log(data);





  });

  //});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tablediv">
  <table cellspacing="0" id="itemtable" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="btnSelect" id="chk" name="chk" /></td>
      <th scope="col"> SIno</th>
      <th scope="col">Item name</th>
      <th scope="col">Item code</th>
      <th scope="col">Supplier</th>
      <th scope="col">Received qty</th>
      <th scope="col">Accepted qty</th>
      <th scope="col">Rejected qty</th>
      <th scope="col">Remarks</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="btnSelect" id="chk" name="chk" /></td>
      <td> 1 </td>
      <td> biscuit </td>
      <td>e123</td>
      <td>abc company</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>waste</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="btnSelect" id="chk" name="chk" /></td>
      <td> 2 </td>
      <td> chocolate </td>
      <td>e526</td>
      <td>xyz company</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>waste</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="button" value="Save the record" id="saverecord" class="button0">
</div>
```

DOnt use this context because your click event is the save button

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can we include any code like to get the table rows only when ".btnSelect:checked" is checked?

Comment: `$(".btnSelect:checked")` will only get the  checked checkbox

Comment: yes correct. but is there any possibility to current row fetch code should execute only when checked. because in current code, i cant not get the data when there is no check box is selected. but piece of code which used for getting row data is getting executed. is there any way to avoid that

Answer (score 1):

You can use [checked](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp) property from the DOM object.

**For exmaple**

```
$("#itemtable").on('click', '.btnSelect', function() {
    if(this.checked){
        // get the current row 
        alert("i am inside dddd");
        var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");

        var col1 = currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text(); // get SI no from checkbox
        var col2 = currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text(); // get item name
        var col3 = currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").text(); // get item code
        var col4 = currentRow.find("td:eq(3)").text(); // get supplier
        var col5 = currentRow.find("td:eq(4)").text(); // get received qty
        var col6 = $(currentRow).find("td:eq(5) input[type='text']").val(); // get accepted qty
        var col7 = $(currentRow).find("td:eq(6) input[type='text']").val(); // get rejected qty
        var col8 = $(currentRow).find("td:eq(7) input[type='text']").val(); // get remarks

        var data = col1 + "\n" + col2 + "\n" + col3 + "\n" + col4 + "\n" + col5 + "\n" + col6 + "\n" + col7 + "\n" + col8;

        alert(data);
    }

});
```

I have made an exmaple on jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/fcaj5g52/1/

Answer (score 0):

Reason of this - you need to use `change` event when you work with checkboxes, because they have state, like this:

`$(document).on('change', '.btnSelect', function() {`

I use `$(document)` in my test because you did not post rest of you code.

Answer (score 0):

just check a condition that the check box is checked or not

```
    var isChecked= document.getElementById("btnSelect").checked;
    if(isChecked){
       // write your code here
}
```